# IndexError caused by ""[0] in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = ''
# case 1
print(s[0])
# case 2
print(s[:1])
print(s[0:1])
```

In the first case I get an `IndexError: string index out of range`, yet the second case is perfectly correct. I'm confused; shouldn't they be the same? In both cases we're printing the character at position 0 in the string. I can get the idea of the the Error, after-all, there are no characters in the string, but I'd expect both cases to give the same Error.

Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd are an empty subset, same as `s[100:2000]`, they don't give index errors.  Conceptually that is fine, because lists have a way to represent no match (`[]`), while indexes do not (e.g. can't be `None`, or any value, since that could be the content of that index)

Comment: Why do you expect an error?  The documentation on slicing is quite clear on how it handles slice bounds out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices are more forgiving than indexing.  If your slice indexes are out of bounds, you'll get an empty sequence or string.  If you index a character that doesn't exist, you get an error as you've discovered.